# How do you convert from an Unboxed Vector to a JS TypedArray on GHCJS?

Tags: javascript, haskell, ghcjs

I have an element of type `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector Word32`. I want to convert that to a native JS `TypedArray` (an `Uint32Array`, specifically). I'm aware of `toJsArray` and `toJsValListOf`, but both functions deal with lists, not vectors, and are inefficient. How can I convert an unboxed `Vector` directly to a JS `TypedArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this up to marshalling to an `Int32Array` instead of an `Uint32Array`; probably someone who has actually known GHCJS for more than the one hour I've put into this will be able to expand on this so that you get your `Uint32Array` (or you can just make a hacked-up version of `GHCJS.Buffer` that supports a `getUint32Array` operation).

The idea is to get the `ByteArray` underlying the `Vector` representation, and then `slice` it so that only the relevant portion remains:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import Data.Word

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base as B
import qualified Data.Vector.Primitive as P
import GHCJS.Types
import qualified GHCJS.Buffer as Buffer
import JavaScript.TypedArray (Int32Array)

-- TODO: generalize this to all types that support unboxed vectors...
toI32Array :: Vector Word32 -> Int32Array
toI32Array (B.V_Word32 (P.Vector offset len bs)) =
    js_slice offset (offset + len) $ Buffer.getInt32Array (Buffer.fromByteArray bs)


foreign import javascript unsafe "$3.slice($1, $2)" js_slice :: Int -> Int -> Int32Array -> Int32Array
-- should be
-- foreign import javascript unsafe "$3.slice($1, $2)" js_slice :: Int -> Int -> SomeTypedArray a m -> SomeTypedArray a m
-- but alas, JavaScript.TypedArray.Internal.Type is a hidden module
```

Here's some example code using it:

```
v :: Vector Word32
v = V.fromList [1, 2, 3]

foreign import javascript unsafe "console.debug($1);" js_debug :: JSVal -> IO ()

main = do
    let v' = toI32Array v
    js_debug $ jsval v'
```

If you look at the console in a browser, you can check that `jsval v'` does indeed have type `Int32Array`.

Comment: Cool! A bit too late for me, though - I ended up figuring I could just pass a ByteString's Ptr directly to JavaScript on the FFI. I then used the lib Spool to convert from unboxed vectors to bytestrings without copying.

Comment: @Viclib, could you explain how you did that? I'm currently trying to figure out how to get a typed array from a bytestring and I'm having trouble.

Comment: I explained. You have a Haskell ByteString, right? Send it to a JavaScript function (anything you write using the FFI) as an argument. Use `console.log` on it. You'll see the data is all there as different buffer types, you can just chose one.

Comment: @Viclib Is there an instance of `(IsJSVal ByteString)` somewhere that I need to be importing? You can't call `jsval` on `ByteString` without it.

Comment: ... I really don't remember... [this](http://lpaste.net/154691) is the relevant code I wrote, though. I've looked at it, seems like like you just need to convert the ByteString to a CString with `B.useAsCString`....